# Why the function space $V^X$ has dimension $|X| \text{dim}V$ when $X$ is finite

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am reading about the [examples of vector space on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_vector_spaces#Several_variables). One is the function space defined as the following,

> Let $X$ be an arbitrary set and $V$ an arbitrary vector space over $F$. The space of all functions from $X$ to $V$ is a vector space over $F$ under pointwise addition and multiplication. That is, let $f : X → V$ and $g : X → V$ denote two functions, and let $α∈F$. We define
>
> $(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$
>
> $(\alpha f)(x) = \alpha f(x)$
>
> where the operations on the right hand side are those in $V$. The zero vector is given by the constant function sending everything to the zero vector in $V$. The space of all functions from $X$ to $V$ is commonly denoted $V^X$.
> If $X$ is finite and $V$ is finite-dimensional then $V^X$ has dimension $|X|(\text{dim} V)$, otherwise the space is infinite-dimensional (uncountably so if $X$ is infinite).

However wiki does not give any proof with above claim of the dimension of such function space. Anyone can help with a proof or a reference to some proof? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $\{ e_i \mid i \in I \}$ be a basis for $V$.

You can check that a basis for $V^X$ is given by the set
$$\{ f_{x,i} \mid x \in X,\ i \in I \}$$
where $f_{x,i} : X \to V$ is the function defined by
$$f_{x,i}(y) = \begin{cases} e_i & \text{if } y=x \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
for all $y \in X$.

This basis has $|X| \cdot |I|$ elements, and so $\dim(V^X) = |X| \cdot \dim(V)$.

This is true even when $V$ is infinite-dimensional (but not if $X$ is infinite).